# swift3 how can i access original app db from widget(extension)

Tags: ios, database, swift3, widget

In swift3 Xcode8 iOS10

I want to import the DB data of the original app from the widget.

But apps and widgets have different DB paths.

So I want to get the App DB path from the widget.

What can I do?

Comment: How are you storing your data? CoreData, SQLite, Files, etc?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create an App Group and share data through the shared folder of the App Group. Apple documents the process [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/ExtensionScenarios.html).